# Getting the Site URL Including the Front Base

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, site-url, home-url

If my permalink structure is set to `/blog/%postname%/`, how can I retrieve a URL for my site which retrieves `domain.com/blog/`?

With the permalink structure mentioned above, when using `site_url();`, it displays `domain.com/` when I'm looking to easily get the site's URL including the front base.

Maybe I'm unclear about what the "front base" actually is.

I'm under the impression that the front base is your "Permalink Structure". (Stored in the option `permalink_structure`)

I've tried `home_url();` and `site_url();` ... Both output just `domain.com/`

I'm thinking about just using `site_url();` then retrieving the option `permalink_structure`, parsing the contents of the option myself, then appending it to the `site_url();` function.

```
$permalink_structure = get_option('permalink_structure');
$front_base = preg_replace('#(\%)(.*)(\%/)#si', '', $permalink_structure);
echo site_url($front_base, 'http').PHP_EOL;
```

Is there an easier way to get the site's URL including the front base?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the value of `front` in the global `$wp_rewrite`:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
echo $wp_rewrite->front;
// or
echo home_url( $wp_rewrite->front );
```

Though that is probably of limited use, as the front base isn't necessarily an existing page, and may 404 in many cases. If you're using that value to prepend to other URLs, you're likely doing it wrong.

If you want the page designated as the posts page, that value is stored in the `page_for_posts` option:

```
echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

I was about to suggest something like the function bellow, but *lets face it @Milo's answer is just a bit smarter*, so just for completeness reason and because I already wrote it down.

```
function wpse163163_site_url_with_fix_permalink_base() {
    return 
        get_site_url()
        . '/'
        . preg_replace(
            '/\%([a-z0-9]+?)\%/i',
            '',
            str_replace(
                '/',
                '',
                get_option('permalink_structure')
            )
        )
        . '/';
}
```

Comment: Had basically the same solution in mind, but could not formulate it :-)

Comment: TBH I pretty much had it in store from a different but similar use case. @PieterGoosen

Comment: Little bit of cheating never hurt anyone :-) Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get link like this.

```
<?php echo home_url( '/blog' ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo home_url( '/' ) . 'blog'; ?>
```

Comment: Well, yeah. Ideally that would be nice if you knew what the front base was. What if you don't know what the front base is? AKA working in a plugin, which the front base could be different on several sites using the plugin. That's why I was going to retrieve the contents of `permalink_structure` option, and parse it myself, then append to `home_url();` or `site_url();`. I was just curious if there was an easier way.

Comment: Then there is not way. Either install WordPress in `domain.com/blog` folder.

Comment: Also why do you need to get front base? Most of the time, if you need to include files then you can use `ABSPATH`.

Comment: I have a plugin which needs to know the post type URLs and taxonomy URLs. As you know, post types and taxonomies can have the front base appended.